# Science answers "how" and "what" but not "why"

Tags: soft-question

I'm a high schooler who naively, for the past few weeks, asked questions that were impossible to answer. I asked "why" questions until I realized that asking "why" questions were the wrong questions to ask in science. When I've tried to naively answer those questions, I was frustrated because I couldn't find an answer. Therefore I wrote a few paragraphs about asking the right questions in the answer below so that newbies like myself can avoid the frustrating process I went through.

Comment: Why didn’t you post your "why" questions on the philosophy Stack...

Comment: Because... I encountered this while studying science not philsophy

Comment: Science and philosophy are linked in the real world - but (arificially) separated in the Stacks....

Comment: First, there isn't a question, which is expected on a *Question & Answer* site. Second, the supposed question one might get out of this isn't a physics question but a [philosophy.se] one.

Comment: *Why do inertial and gravitational masses coincide?* That was a crucial "why" in physics which produced (together with other ideas) the general theory of  relativity.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the way that most people think about it. There are two current theories of physics that are the "most deep" to our knowledge: quantum field theory (more specifically the Standard Model) and general relativity. (It turns out they are not compatible but let's ignore that for now.)

These two theories are, as far as we know, the "rules of the game." If you know these two theories, you can, in principle, answer "why" questions about the less fundamental theories (Newtonian mechanics, special relativity, quantum mechanics, etc.) If you know quantum field theory, you can figure out the rules of quantum mechanics (which is different because quantum mechanics, unlike quantum field theory, deals with particles moving much slower than light) and then determine "why" atoms have the electron orbitals they have. But until you know the deeper theory, it doesn't really make sense to ask "why."

For example, "why are photons massless?" is an interesting question. When you first learn special relativity, it's just an empirical fact. When you learn quantum field theory, you learn that the masslessness of the photon comes from the fact that the electromagnetic field is a U(1) "gauge field," allowing you to in some sense answer "why" it is massless. However, you could then just ask "why is the electromagnetic field a gauge field?" and then you are back where you started.

Presumably, if physicists had the theory of quantum gravity, they could answer many "why" questions about quantum field theory and general relativity. However, they still wouldn't be able to answer a new crop of "why" questions about the new theory of quantum gravity.

To summarize, once you know the "rules of the game" you can answer "why" questions which follow from those rules, but you can't ask why the rules are the way they are.

Comment: I hope I understand that one day. So if the two theories are incompatible, one theory is wrong?

Comment: It's not like one is right and one is wrong. Both are superbly successful in their respective domains. However, just like Newtonian mechanics was extremely successful in its domain of applicability, it was later found to be incorrect for objects moving close to the speed of light, and needed to be subsumed by a deeper theory, the theory of special relativity. Both QFT and general relativity will likely be subsumed by a deeper unifying theory. String theory is one possible candidate, but it is still incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

When you ask "why," you're asking the purpose of the creation of something. If you ask the creator of that something why he created it, he can tell you. But if you don't know the creator and his motivations, you'll never know the purpose of his creation -- you can only guess. For example, if you ask Elon Musk "why he began SpaceX," he will tell you that he wants to benefit mankind. But if you ask "why do we exist" or "why does gravity exist," you will have to ask the creator of the universe, but we don't know the creator and therefore we won't know.

On the other hand, when you ask "what" or "how," you're asking for the description of that something, the relationship of that something with another, or/and the process of that something. For example, if you ask "what's the relationship between mass and acceleration," the physicist can tell you that force is dependent on both mass and acceleration. But the physicist or anyone else won't be able to explain "why force exists" or "why force is dependent on both mass or acceleration" -- those questions we will never know the answers to unless we meet the creator of the universe. For now, I think I'll leave that up to philosophy, religion, etc.